# mysql Undo log record is too big

Tags: mysql

I have a strange problem with a particular database:

```
mysql> update person set last_name=null where first_name='john';
ERROR 1713 (HY000): Undo log record is too big.
```

What can be the problem?
(I've already googled quite a log)

mysql 5.7.20 installed with brew on Mac OSX 10.12.6.

```
show table status where name = 'person'
    -> ;
+--------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name               | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+--------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| person             | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 650918 |           4322 |  2813853696 |               0 |   1369833472 |   6291456 |           NULL | 2017-09-12 14:31:20 | 2017-10-24 12:37:03 | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+--------------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Possibly related? https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88150 (slightly different issue here though)

Comment: i just let a comment there. let's see.